# Find the density function of the median of a uniformly distributed random sample

Tags: statistics, median

I'm stuck on a question that asks me to find the density function of the median. I am not given anything aside from the information that $Y_1, Y_2,..., Y_{2n+1}$ is a random sample of uniformly distributed numbers from (0,1).

Is the answer just $\cfrac {1}{2(b-a)}$ and am I just overthinking this?

EDIT: Looking at the above, I just realised that that isn't even a function, just a number. Do I need to use order statistics to answer this question?

Comment: I think you should consider the order statistics.  Since the random sample has an odd number of points, then it contains its median.  So $Y_{(n)}$ will be the median.

Comment: Until you have a mathematical feel for how to go about finding the probability density function of the median for an odd sample size from a uniform (0,1) distribution, you might first consider taking random samples and constructing a sample estimate of the probability density function.

Comment: What is the definition of sample median? Do you see why the sample median is an order statistic? If you do, there isn't much else to do since the pdf of a single order statistic has a known distribution.